# How to add rings that intersect with a polygons edge in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing, nodes

I need to amend the area of an existing polygon so that I can draw another polygon (of another typology in the amended area). Normally, I would manually move the nodes but this will be very time consuming due to the curving edges of the polygons.

Is there a way I can use the add rings button to do this?

(so far it is not letting me amend an area that intersects the edge of the polygon)

Or if not, is there an alternative option?

The area I need to remove lies above the footpath in the screen grab below

[image: Original Polygon requiring amendment]

Comment: Could you add an image that shows what you want to do?